# Converting a 24 hour format date string to Date and it does not match

Tags: ios, swift, date

I am converting this 24 hour format string `"2019-01-10 21:00:40"` to a Date object but what I am getting is this `2019-01-10 13:00:40`. I am using the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` to convert the string to date object. What seems to be the problem here?

I am using this String Extension to convert string to date:

```
    func toDateWithFormat(_ format:String) -> Date{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: self) else {
        fatalError("ERROR: Date conversion failed due to mismatched format.")
    }
    return date
}
```

Comment: What about adding the code you tried?

Comment: what is your date format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"?

Comment: Could you give some code you use to convert? I suppose that you get Date at default time zone which is different from your time zone. Actually class Date is time zone independent. So to get localised date you should use class Calendar.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening due to different time zone. you have to add the time zone into the date.

Use this method to converting your timestamp to date

```
class func timeStampToDate(_timestamp : String, _dateFormat : String) -> String{

        var LOCAL_TIME_ZONE: Int { return TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT() }

        var date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(_timestamp)!)
        date += TimeInterval(truncating: LOCAL_TIME_ZONE as NSNumber)
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT") //Set timezone that you want
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = _dateFormat //Specify your format that you want
        let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        return strDate
    }
```

And when you get the strDate from this method. convert to a date object. you will get the currect date object